# How To Get Count of the records in sql

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables in my database one tblNews and another tblNewsComments
I want to select 10 records from tblNewsComments than have must Comments of news
I used this query but it give an error

```
SELECT tblNews.id, 
       tblNews.newsTitle, 
       tblNews.createdate, 
       tblNews.viewcount, 
       COUNT(tblNewsComments.id) AS comcounts
FROM tblNews 
   INNER JOIN tblNewsComments ON tblNews.id = tblNewsComments.newsID
GROUP BY tblNews.id
```

Comment: Would you mind specifying what error that is?

Comment: this error: Column 'dbo.tblNewsTitle' is invalid in select list because is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace

```
GROUP BY tblNews.id
```

With

```
GROUP BY tblNews.id, 
         tblNews.newsTitle, 
         tblNews.createdate, 
         tblNews.viewcount
```

All the expressions in the SELECT list should be in the GROUP BY or inside an aggregate function.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found this to be an annoyance in SQL. There's nothing logically wrong with your query; you're grouping by news item and selecting various attributes of the news item, and then selecting the count of comments linked to the news item. That makes sense.

The error arises because the SQL engine isn't smart enough to realize that all the columns in tblNews are at the same data context, and that grouping by tblNews.id effectively guarantees that there will only be one newsTitle, createdate, and viewcount for each group. It *should* be able to realize that, I think, and carry out the query. But it doesn't do that; the only column it considers to be unique in the group data context is the exact column that you grouped by, id.

One solution, as Multisync just posted, is to group by ALL the columns you want to include in the select clause. I don't think this is the best solution, however, as you shouldn't have to specify all those columns in the group by clause, and that would force you to keep adding to that list whenever you want to add a new TblNews column to the select clause.

The solution I've always used is to wrap the column in an ineffectual aggregate function in the select clause; I always use `max()`:

```
select
    tblNews.id,
    max(tblNews.newsTitle),
    max(tblNews.createdate),
    max(tblNews.viewcount),
    count(tblNewsComments.id) comcounts
from
    tblNews
    inner join tblNewsComments on tblNews.id=tblNewsComments.newsID
group by
    tblNews.id
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or with subquery:

```
SELECT n.id, 
   n.newsTitle, 
   n.createdate, 
   n.viewcount, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblNewsComments c ON n.id = c.newsID) AS comcounts
FROM tblNews n
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to select one column and group by another...other column will not work as they are not in the aggregate function.

```
SELECT tblNews.id, COUNT(tblNewsComments.newsID) AS comcounts  
FROM tblNews 
   INNER JOIN tblNewsComments ON tblNews.id = tblNewsComments.newsID
GROUP BY tblNews.id
```

[Read Here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx)